# What's the opposite of "main diagonal"?

Tags: matrices

This matrix has only '1's on its main diagonal:

$A = \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$

But whats the opposite of main diagonal?

I want to say something like:
"There are only '0's on the NOT-main-diagonal"

Can someone help me with a word?

Comment: "not-main-diagonal" can mean either "not-(main-diagonal)" (i.e. the entries which are not on the main diagonal), or "(not-main)-diagonal" (i.e. the _diagonal_ which goes from top right to bottom left, and therefore is not the main diagonal). I think you mean the first one, and the answer below is correct in that case. But just to be sure: which one do you mean?

Comment: yes, the first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are known as **off-diagonal elements**.

Check out the Wikipedia links:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_diagonal
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-diagonal_element